# Centering caption on a img tag inside <a> parent tags

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I'd like to center a caption on an `img` tag contained within `<a></a>` tags.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<body> 
   <ul>
       <li>
          <a>
            <p><img></p>
          </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
<body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS stylesheet:

```
#navigator ul li a p img{
   margin: 0em 0 0 0em;
   display: inline;
}

#navigator ul li a {
   float:left;
   padding: 0 0 0 0;
   margin:0 auto 0 1em;
}

#navigator ul li a p{
   padding: 0 0 0 0;
   margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

How might I go about doing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You could try asking an actual question ;-)

Comment: Lol, I guess I overlooked at it.

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example of your code? You can use [http://dummyimage.com/](http://dummyimage.com/) for a dummy image.

Comment: I need to log in in other to get the url and show it to you guys?

Comment: Ok this is the link   http://jsfiddle.net/8Ewjq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this JS Fiddle showing how I'd do it: http://jsfiddle.net/YmWnh/

I re-worked portions of your code (no closing body tag) and added some content to get the centered effect.  If you structure the HTML like this:

```
<ul id="navigator">
  <li>
    <a href="#">The Caption</a>
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Caption 2</a>
    <img src="image2.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then this CSS gets the job done:

```
#navigator li {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#navigator li img, #navigator li a {
   display: block;
}

#navigator li a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The width on the li constrains the child image and anchor elements, and allows them to be centered (or not) against the li.

Comment: Katiek You nailed it, in other words the li need to have a with, what about the disploc for img and a you have put in there what's the significance of it. Great job it works.

Comment: I can see you have a different approach on how to do it in the jsfiddle. I will take that approach in consideration to a more semantic html to CSS code

Comment: display: block; makes elements which would otherwise be inline behave as blocks.  See http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/, for example.  
Yeah, I made some pretty severe edits to your first set of code.  I just went with the simplest method possible to illustrate what you needed.  ;)